# QT5 theme not applied on my own applications

Tags: themes, qt

I set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` at login. Installed applications such as `designer` and `qt5ct` itself respect that, and use the theme.

However, the applications I make or build myself (e.g. python application using PyQt5) do not. I've tried starting them on the command line with setting the environment, but it does not work either:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct python3 scan # scan is my program
```

How can I make sure the Qt theme applies to all applications using Qt?

Comment: Try perhaps using Kvantum as described [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/use-custom-themes-for-qt-applications.html).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. I installed and selected a kvantum style with `kvantummanager`. Then `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum python3 scan` still uses the old theme.